# Dropdown menu in firefox being displayed horizontally

Tags: html, firefox, drop-down-menu

I have a simple dropdown menu that looks like this in firefox:

[image: dropdown menu]

When I click on the dropdown menu, the menu renders very strangely:

[image: strange rendering]

It renders fine in Chrome:

[image: looks ok in Chrome...]

As far as I can tell, the HTML is ok...

```
<select class="date">

    <option value="Mon Oct 21 2013 15:08:57 GMT+0100 (BST)">
        Today

    </option>

    <option value="Tue Oct 22 2013 15:08:57 GMT+0100 (BST)">
        Tomorrow

    </option>

    <option selected="" value="Wed Oct 23 2013 15:08:57 GMT+0100 (BST)">

            Wednesday

    </option>

    <option value="Thu Oct 24 2013 15:08:57 GMT+0100 (BST)">

            Thursday

    </option>

    <option value="Fri Oct 25 2013 15:08:57 GMT+0100 (BST)">

            Friday

    </option>

    <option value="Sat Oct 26 2013 15:08:57 GMT+0100 (BST)">

            Saturday

    </option>

    <option value="Sun Oct 27 2013 14:08:57 GMT+0000 (GMT)">

            Sunday

    </option>

</select>
```

I've never seen a dropdown render like that before and am pretty confused as to what's going on, would appreciate any help.

Comment: can you please post the css(i.e date calss and if there is any class which is applied SELECT itself) which is applied to the select ??

Comment: Ooops! My mistake, I had this in the css:

   .time-box * {
       display: inline-block;
   }

I added

    .time-box select option {
        display: block;
    }

And it fixed it! Thanks for the pointer Dhaval!